# socket.io slow on mobile device

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a node.js app that sends live data to the client via socket.io (Websocket transport) to draw a canvas (the client receives and uses data to draw to canvas).

I use `socket.io-client` to connect to the socket.io server.
This works fine (at least to an extent) on PC but very slow on mobile devices (that support WebSocket).

Note: App is hosted on Azure and I am saying most data on Local Storage for better performance.

What can be the cause of the lagging and frequent disconnection on mobile phones but good connections on PCs?

Comment: Are you using any compression to reduce bandwidth?

Comment: @WLGfx no, please. Kindly enlighten me on this.

Comment: Depending on the quality you are after or not too bothered about it then use either PNG for best quality or JPG for much smaller bandwidth. The server can compress, send, and the device can decompress. Either way, less bandwidth and a faster frame rate. The only downside is higher CPU usage. Or if another client is sending data to the server, then that client can compress the image and send to the server, the server doesn't have to change it, just send it back out to other clients.